# .get_text() not properly working on span using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the body of the [following article](https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/up-plans-100-000-covid-beds-as-325-000-stranded-labourers-return-in-2-weeks-120051100865_1.html). This is the code I am using:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a_url = "https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/up-plans-100-000-covid-beds-as-325-000-stranded-labourers-return-in-2-weeks-120051100865_1.html"
y = requests.get(a_url, headers=headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(y.content, 'html.parser')
body = soup2.find('span',class_= "p-content").get_text()
```

I believe I should only be getting the text, but this is the output:

```
\nspan.p-content div[id^="div-gpt"]{line-height:0;font-size:0}\n\r\n\tAmid the large-scale 
influx of migrant labourers due to the lockdown, the Uttar Pradesh government is planning to make arrangements for 100,000 covid-19 beds across the state.\n\r\n\tAs commercial and 
industrial activity in UP has started reviving under the controlled relaxations announced by the 
government, the state is gearing up to deal with exigencies, with more than a million migrants
 expected to arrive in the near future.document.write("<!--");if(isUserBanner=="free"&&
(displayConBanner==1))document.write("-->");googletag.cmd.push(function()
{googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot(\'/6516239/outofpage_1x1_desktop\',\'div-gpt-ad-1490771277198-
0\').addService(googletag.pubads());googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();googletag.enableSer
vices();});\n\ngoogletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display(\'div-gpt-ad-1490771277198-
0\');});\n\nvar banHeight=$(".article-middle-banner iframe").height();if(banHeight<=1)
{$(".article-middle-banner").height(0);$(".article-middle-
banner").next().next().remove();}displayConBanner=1;\n\r\n\tIn fact, some 325,000 stranded
 workers have returned in the past two weeks by either train or bus.\n\r\n\tSo far, the state 
government has made arrangements for more than 52,000 covid-19 beds in the public and private 
sectors hospitals.\n\r\n\tChairing a review meeting here, chief minister Yogi Adityanath 
directed officials to ramp up the number of covid beds to 75,000 by May 20 and eventually 
upgrade it to about 100,000 beds in the coming weeks.\nALSO READ: Coronavirus LIVE: 4,213 new 
cases; govt says India recovery rate 31.15%\n\n\r\n\t“The higher number of covid-19 beds would
 ensure that the patients get best medical care in the state whenever required,” UP additional
 chief secretary Awanish Kumar Awasthi said this evening.\n\r\n\tThe state has created an 
elaborate network of level 1, 2 and 3 covid-19 hospitals across the state, of which the L1 
pertain to the primary care at the district level, followed by L2 and L3 at the state level 
having superior medical facilities and equipped with oxygen and ventilator support 
respectively.\n\r\n\tBesides, the state has planned to increase the daily testing capacity to 
10,000 per day from less than 5,000 at present. The government is promoting pool testing too so that a larger number of people could be tested in a given period of time.\n\r\n\tAt present, the instance of covid-19 in UP has been the highest in the 21-40 year age category with more than 48 per cent of the total cases in UP, followed by 41-60 year, 0-20 year and 61+ year categories reporting about 26 per cent, 18 per cent and 8 per cent cases respectively.\n\r\n\t“The percentage of men patients in UP is 78.5 per cent compared to women at 21.5 per cent,” UP principal secretary, medical and health Amit Mohan Prasad said.\n\r\n\tA majority of the coronavirus patients in UP have been asymptomatic that is the patients do not experience any known symptoms of disease, but are found to be active in sample testing.\n\r\n\tMeanwhile, the state has set the target of arranging for 50-55 trains on a daily basis to speedily evacuate its workers stranded in other states, including Maharashtra, Gujarat, Punjab, Karnataka etc.\n\r\n\t“We are creating a database of migrant workers, who are coming back, so that we could identify their unique skill sets for providing them with suitable employment opportunities in UP itself,” Awasthi informed. The state is looking to provide jobs to more than two million migrant workers.\n
```

Some extra HTML and thee JS for the google ads are also being retrieved. How do I solve this?

Comment: Use `soup.select(" <tag you want to select> ")`. It is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some unwanted text in script and style tag you need to remove before taking data using get_text()

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen(
        "https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/up-plans-100-000-covid-beds-as-325-000-stranded-labourers-return-in-2-weeks-120051100865_1.html") as response:
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
[s.extract() for s in soup('script')]
[s.extract() for s in soup('style')]
body = soup.find('span',class_= "p-content").get_text()
print(body)
```

you can use this to take all script and style tag

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

# a_url = "https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/up-plans-100-000-covid-beds-as-325-000-stranded-labourers-return-in-2-weeks-120051100865_1.html"
# y = requests.get(a_url, headers=headers)
# soup2 = BeautifulSoup(y.content, 'html.parser')
# body = soup2.find('span',class_= "p-content").get_text()


def crawl():
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/up-plans-100-000-covid-beds-as-325-000-stranded-labourers-return-in-2-weeks-120051100865_1.html") as response:
        html = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    for b in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'p-content'}):
        print(b.text)

crawl()
```

I think you get thing you want.

I want to describe the code detail. But I hard to writing english. so I wish to understand yourself!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a_url = "https://www.business-standard.com/article/current-affairs/up-plans-100-000-covid-beds-as-325-000-stranded-labourers-return-in-2-weeks-120051100865_1.html"
y = requests.get(a_url)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(y.content, 'html.parser')
body = soup2.select('span.p-content p')
for item in body:
    print(item.getText())
```

Don't let Yogi change your name, LOL(IYKWIM).